# jQuery rollover image with data-other-src only works when it's on a certain place

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mouseenter

Soooo... I found this nice code on here, to make a rollover image that also works on mobile. This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('img.hophop').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).attr(
            {src: $(this).attr('data-other-src'), 'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src')}
        )
   });
    $('img.hophop').bind('touchstart touchend', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr(
            {src: $(this).attr('data-other-src'), 'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src')}
        )
   });
});
```

And it works like a charm, except... I'm using it with WordPress. And every time I move from text editor to wysiwyg, wordpress changes my links. From this:

```
<img data-other-src="http://www.toeps.nl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MG_3502voor.jpg" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-61182 hophop" src="http://www.toeps.nl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MG_3502na.jpg" alt="_MG_3502na" width="1080" height="1080" />
```

To this:

```
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-61182 hophop" src="http://www.toeps.nl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MG_3502na.jpg" alt="_MG_3502na" width="1080" height="1080" data-other-src="http://www.toeps.nl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/MG_3502voor.jpg" />
```

So it moves the data-other-src to the back and all of a sudden, it doesn't work anymore?! I'm breaking my head as to why. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I SOLVED IT!

Apparently my WordPress retina plug-in added some src-set things for responsiveness bla bla. Disabled that, and it's working!

Comment: [Keep HTML format when switching from Visual to HTML editor](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17123/keep-html-format-when-switching-from-visual-to-html-editor)

Comment: Thanks, that will solve the issue but I still don't understand WHY it happens...? And if I'd ever make a plugin of this code, it wouldn't be the nicest solution to tell people to install the other plugin as well, or otherwise it won't work...

Comment: From the linked question: `this problem is rooted in the wordpress core code not in TinyMCE or due to browser compatility problems`.

Comment: I understand, but my question is not really focussed on WordPress: I want to know WHY it is that, when the data-other-src is in the back of the code, it doesn't work anymore? Why is that? With all the other things (like alt, class etc) it doesn't matter WHERE it is standing, as long as it's somewhere in between the img-tags.